# How to check whether an ajax request has allready been sent with Jquery?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am using an Ajax request to post a form with Jquery.

```
$.ajax( 
        { 
            type: "POST", 
            url: "login.php", 
            data: $("#signin").serialize(),
            dataType: "json",
            cache: false,
            success: function(data, textStatus) {
                if (data.redirect) {
                    window.location.replace(data.redirect);
                }
                else {
                    $('#some').fadeOut(200);
                    $('#some2').fadeIn(200);
                    $("#some3").html(data.form);
                    $("#some").delay(2000).fadeOut(200);
                    $('#some2').delay(2800).fadeIn(300);
                }
            }           
        });
```

Now the ajax request will take place as soon as you click on a button "Login". The problem now is that if you press the button more than once the else case will be executed several times which will cause #some, #some2 and #some3 to fade out and in several times. So how could I check whether the request has allready been sent (without having to write something into my db)?

Comment: Remove the hook on the button as soon as it is clicked, attach it again on completion in the handlers for success or error

Comment: Or disable the button to give some feedback to the user at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4063651/337294):

You can use [.one()](http://api.jquery.com/one/) method and set it again in ajax callback.

```
function doAjax(){
    // Your Ajax call.
    $.ajax({..., complete: function() {
        // Ajax call done, re-enabling the button/link
        $("#buttonId").one('click', doAjax);
    }, ...});
}

$("#buttonId").one('click', doAjax);
```

Comment: If I put the first `$("#buttonId").one('click', doAjax);` into the success case behind the else case then the link will be re-enabled immediately giving me the same problem...

Comment: I'd put it in `complete` callback instead of success so if the call was not successful, the event will be rebinded again.

Comment: I´ve put it into the `complete` callback now but it seems that `$("#buttonId").one('click', doAjax);` inside the complete callback will be  executed before the else case in the `success` callback has finished...

Comment: Take a look at `complete` documentation at http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ : "A function to be called when the request finishes (after success and error callbacks are executed)"

Answer (score 0):

Make boolean flag, say, `login_in_process`, on login check this flag in `true` value. And check this flag on every click if it `true` then make empty return. In success and error callbacks set it in `false` state.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a boolean value to record whether or not it has been clicked:

```
var loginClicked = false;

$('input_button_element').click(function(){
  if (!loginClicked) {
    loginClicked = true;
    // your js here - you may want to add some visual feedback to the user also
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can make a global var

```
var loginClick = false;
```

Inside your method you first check that value

```
if (!loginClick) {
  loginClick = true;
  //your ajax code;
}
```

Comment: The var loginClick = false; I would put into my document.ready part, wouldnt I?
Because my function login is not inside the document.ready part. Does it work like that nevertheless?

Comment: It doesn't make sense. You may put it there, but you also may put it outside the document.ready

Answer (score 0):

You will have to store a boolean in a global scope, e.g. one stored on the window object:

```
if (!window.isClicked) {
    window.isClicked = true;
    ...Do your ajax call here        
}
```

Remember to ALWAYS restore the value of window.isClicked, not only in the success callback of ajax():

```
var jqxhr = $.ajax( ... )
.done(function() {  })
.fail(function() {  })
.always(function() { window.isClicked = false });
```

Comment: Bad practice to flood global scope better is just have variable inside function scope.

Comment: Couldn't agree more. Don't know what I was smoking :)